# BAD_ACCESS_EXEC when adding gestureRecognizer in different class

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to build a generic class with a couple of Gesture Recognizers, so that I can call one method and have both Recognizers added to the view

Here is my class implementation code

```
#import "saUIHelper.h"

@implementation saUIHelper


-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"pan");
}

-(void)handleLP:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}

-(saUIHelper*)initWithView:(UIView*)view
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.myView = view;
        self.myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)start
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer =
    [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
     initWithTarget:self
     action:@selector(handlePan:)];

    [self.myView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpRecognizer =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
     initWithTarget:self
     action:@selector(handleLP:)];

    [self.myView addGestureRecognizer:lpRecognizer];
}

@end
```

And I try to use it like this

```
    UIImage *playImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playBtn"];
    self.playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.playBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, 60.0f, 60.0f);
    self.playBtn.center = CGPointMake(viewWidth/2,(viewHeight/2)-35);
    [self.playBtn setBackgroundImage:playImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.menu addSubview:self.playBtn];

    saUIHelper* helper = [[saUIHelper alloc] initWithView:self.playBtn];
    [helper start];
```

When I run this code and do a Pan or LongPressure gesture on the button I added, I get a crash with BAD_ACCESS_EXEC code

If however instead of calling `[helper start];` I type in the same code as implemented in the start method, and add the `handlePan:` and `handleLP:` callbacks to the main class, I get no issues and everything runs fine

It's obvious I'm doing something very wrong here, not sure if it's threading issues or something else, can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Enable Zombies in Xcode, and you'll be able to get a more detailed error and crash log.

Comment: How do you use helper after [helper start]; line? If you don't use object helper further in code, it gets deallocated after [helper start] call because you don't keep strong reference.

Answer (score 2):

Store a strong reference to `saUIHelper* helper` in your view/viewcontroller so that it doesn't get dealloced. You're probably getting a crash because the target is the helper, which might have been dealloced.

Comment: How dumb do I feel... Thank you for your help, you nailed it